# WPF Chain Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to make a chain binding like this: I have a usercontrol with a dependencyproperty inside a window with similar dependencyproperty. I want to bind the dependencyproperty of the usercontrol to the dependencyproperty of the window.

I created a sample project to demonstrate my problem:

UserControl1 XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Caption}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1 C#:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));
    public string Caption
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"  x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 x:Name="uc" Caption="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWay}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));
    public string Caption
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      (new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { uc.Caption = "YYY"; Caption = "XXX"; }); })).Start();
    }
  }
```

The thing is that when I set Caption to "XXX" (of the Window) I would expect it to also notify the usercontrol and update its Caption, but it doesn't. I would like to avoid Attached dependency properties and avoid code behind as much as possible. Any ideas?

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: In the user control's declaration of the dp, did you consider hooking the property changed call back?  That should bring about the behaviour you're after.

Comment: I had this idea, but I was after a solution with less code behind if there is any.

Comment: See Kess' answer below for the data context collision.  But at the expense of three lines of code in the dependency property, you're creating a matryoshka of Xaml with no real payback.

Comment: @GarryVass I guess I'll go with your suggestion in the end, if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GarryVass Sure :]... I just want to close the question and give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user control along the lines of...

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChainBinding.CaptionGuy"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Grid>
            <Label Name="CaptionLabel"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...and instrument it with your dependency property like this...

```
    #region Caption (DependencyProperty)
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(CaptionGuy),
          new PropertyMetadata{PropertyChangedCallback = CaptionChanged});
    private static void CaptionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CaptionGuy cg = d as CaptionGuy;
        if (cg != null && e.NewValue!=null)
        {
            cg.CaptionLabel.Content = e.NewValue.ToString();
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Then you can deploy it in a WPF application like this...

```
<Grid>
    <chainBinding:CaptionGuy Caption="{Binding VmCaption}"/>
</Grid>
```

And the corresponding View Model (or code-behind if that's your design) would look like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,5), DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            delegate
            {
                VmCaption = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            }, dispatcher);
        dt.Start();
    }
    private string _vmCaption;
    public string VmCaption
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _vmCaption; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _vmCaption)
            {
                _vmCaption = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VmCaption");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This example just updates the caption with the time every 5 seconds.

Of course this answer uses a callback on the dependency property, but this is a matter where circumstantial practicality wins out over declarative programming.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your bindings. By default binding looks for a property on the DataContext property of the control. Every binding has a source and in your case its the DataContext property of the control. So your binding is evaluating to DataContext.Caption. What your really want is to make the source of the binding, the window that has the Caption property. So change the code as indicated below. I tested it on my machine and it works. Remember to initialize the Caption property of the window.

new:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

new:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:current="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="{Binding Caption, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    <current:UserControl1 x:Name="uc" Caption="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: all part of the service :)  Timely edit got you a big 10 points that would otherwise have been jeopardized!  Use the button for Xaml :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried it but unfortunately it does not seem to help - setting <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/> sets the content of the label to its (RelativeSource Self) property Caption, which does not exist (or am I wrong?). And Caption="{Binding Path=Caption, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=OneWay}" sets Caption property of the usercontrol to its own property Caption so its useless (or am I wrong?). However I might have misunderstood something...

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need to find the property from the visual tree so if the User Control is on the main window. The solution above should work.

Comment: Thanks. I have the datacontext set to Window in Window.xaml already - in the <Window ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">... and similarly in the UserControl.

Comment: It depends on what your are doing. However, the data context is usually reserved for view models, so that may not be a good idea. In your case, you just want to bind to the source you want from the visual tree.

Comment: @Kess I am not going with MVVM where I need this... I had that DataContexts set to what you suggested - to the Window and UserControl - from the start though :].. I'll go with property changed callback as Garry suggested in the end. Thanks for your time.

Comment: see the solution again. I made some minor changes and it works on my machine. I tested it by copying and editing your code.

Comment: @Kess Still doesn't work for me :/ - After setting MainWindow's Caption to something the UserControl's Caption remains unchanged.